# Dockable Components in Web Application

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create dock-able widgets in Web application?
Where dock-able widget can be moved out of the window and placed in extended display, and it remain in sync with application state.

Comment: You're asking if you can drag a component off of a web page?

Comment: You can't do that. The element have to stay into the window.

Comment: No, you can't do that.